# I want to build a battery based DC supply for LED mirror that has AC power cable (230VAC)

Tags: inverter, battery-operated, dc-ac

I recently purchased an LED mirror that is AC powered (230VAC). The problem is there is no GPO (power outlet) in the room.

I am trying to make this wireless and wall mounted. I tried researching DC to AC inverters, however they appear to be very large/heavy and powered by a 12VDC socket. This is not practical for the space as I want it to be wall mounted and to have the cables hidden - I can’t connect it to a socket.

**I am looking for suggestions on how to convert DC to 230VAC in a compact way I.e. with battery based supply or other**

Could I engineer a solution with a DC to AC inverter? How could I build it to be battery based instead of a 12VDC socket input?

An example of the inverter I’m looking at can be found here: https://www.jaycar.com.au/150w-450w-surge-12vdc-to-240vac-inverter-with-usb/p/MI5130

Would it be more effective to design the whole circuit rather than using the inverter and engineering a battery based input? If so, can you please provide suggestions on where to start?

Comment: um, that sounds pretty backwards: LEDs need DC, so synthesizing AC from DC (which you tell us nothing about - what's "a small battery pack", actually?), just for it to be converted back to DC sounds unproductive; all these conversions are lossy. Also, you need to ask yourself for how long you want to run the lights – batteries don't run forever...

Comment: also: fair warning: the way you're phrasing this right now sounds like you don't want to engineer anything, just buy a consumer device. **Product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here**, even more so if they're for consumer products, not for components for something you're engineering yourself (and while "I want to build a battery-based supply for an illuminated mirror" is an engineering problem, you're really not stating it as such.)

Comment: [GPO](https://postandparcel.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/SPGPO.jpg)?

Comment: Open the device and look for a LED driver, it will probably look like a small power brick or switching power supply block. Then please post a picture of the label. If this outputs low voltage DC to power the LEDs you'll have a much easier and less dangerous job making a battery powered LED driver with the correct specs.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Marcus it’s engineering because I’m asking if it’s safe to do so or practical/the best way to go about it. A small battery pack is something that I can hide behind the mirror, I’m not sure how many batteries I would need, that’s also where the engineer comes in..  I would need to engineer a solution to connect the batteries (rather than using the 12V socket) The lights will probably run for an hour a day. The mirror only has a wall plug, but as stated in the question I don’t have a power outlet to convert to, I’m looking for suggestions on how to make it batter operated

Comment: Andy GPO - general power outlet :)

Comment: @peufeu thank you! I will do that tonight and post a photo